# Print formatting while taking user input

Tags: java, arrays, input

I have a college assignment where I need to print out items sold by a hardware store, take input from a user, perform some calculations on that input, and then print out an invoice.

I have been able to successfully print out the items sold by the hardware store, but am encountering problems with the `while` loop that takes the input.

The program asks the user to enter a CODE and then asks for the corresponding QUANTITY. This works fine on the first iteration of the loop, but on the second iteration the user prompts for "CODE:" and "QUANTITY:" appear on the same line, despite my use of `println` when prompting the user.

I would greatly appreciate a detailed response appropriate for someone new in programming.

Here's the code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 class HardwareStore {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("WELCOME TO THE HARDWARE STORE!");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");


        String sticky = "G22";
        String keyring = "K13";
        String screwy = "S21";
        String padlock = "I30";


        int stickyprice = 10989;
        int keyringprice = 5655;
        int screwyprice = 1099;
        int padlockprice = 4005;


        System.out.println("CODE\t\tDESCRIPTION\t\t\t\t\tPRICE");
        System.out.println("----\t\t-----------\t\t\t\t\t-----");

        System.out.println(sticky + "\t\tSTICKY Construction Glue, Heavy Duty, \n\t\t7oz, 12 Pack \t\t\t\t\t$" + stickyprice);
        System.out.println(keyring + "\t\tCAR-LO Key Ring, Quick Release, \n\t\t1 Pack\t\t\t\t\t\t$ " + keyringprice);
        System.out.println(screwy + "\t\t!GREAT DEAL! SCREW-DUP Screwy Screws, \n\t\tDry Wall Screws, 3 in. Long, 50 Pack\t\t$ " + screwyprice);
        System.out.println(padlock + "\t\tLET-IT-RAIN, Weather Proof Padlock, \n\t\tPortable, One Push Functionality\t\t$ " + padlockprice);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");


        int i = 10000; 
        String [] usercode = new String[i]; 
        int [] userquantity = new int[i];


        System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER YOUR ORDER:");


        while (true) {
            System.out.println("CODE: (X to terminate)");
            usercode[i] = in.nextLine();

            if (usercode[i].equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("QUANTITY: ");
            userquantity[i] = in.nextInt();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, feel free to edit the rest of the code and give me tips on how to proceed with the program. Or what are some of the ways I can improve.

Comment: You should accept an answer on your previous question.

Comment: How do I do that? I did click YES to "Was this post helpful to you?" to one of the answers. I will do it again if that's what I gotta do. Maybe I didn't do it right the last time.

Comment: @nickecarlo there's a check mark next to the answer that you click.  That sets it as the `accepted` one.

Comment: @nickecarlo, next to an answer there is a tick, click that an it will turn green to indicate that is a correct answer.

Comment: @nickecarlo [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured it out and accepted one. Sorry, I am pretty new here. I am sure it can be annoying for you guys to deal with noobs like me but I will try to learn how to better use this website as soon as I can.

Comment: @nickecarlo we were all noobs once.  don't worry.  Hell, I still am.

Comment: @nickecarlo: No worries - everything is fine now :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you enter the `QUANTITY` you're pressing enter.  That `newline` character isn't used by `in.nextInt();`, it remains in the scanner buffer, until you roll around to `in.nextLine()` again.

At that point `in.nextLine()` reads until it finds a newline  character, which just happens to be the next one in the buffer.  So it skips straight to `QUANTITY` again.

Comment: if you need more explanation, feel free to comment here nick.  I'll update my answer with more info.

Comment: Thanks. Would adding an in.nextLine(); fix the problem here? Or am I completely off about this.

Comment: @nickecarlo yes, in this instance it would.  It would consume the `\n` for the next loop around.  This is not always going to be best practice though.  I don't remember if Java allows input separation with a space from the command line, as C++ does.  IF that is the case, the `in.nextLine()` would cause problems if you, for instance, entered "STICKY (SPACE) 3"

Comment: Okay, tested that and it seems to have worked. Thanks for the help, its weird that the books don't talk about it. I will post more of this program when I have worked on it more and need help, should I edit this same post, since its related to this program, or make a new one?

Comment: @nickecarlo see the edit I made in my last comment.  I'd say open another question, unless it is on the same topic (issues with reading from command line)

Comment: I tested the program in the last couple of minutes with all kindsa different inputs, it doesn't throw any errors. So I think what you said helped. No errors, and the printout is normal. Thank you so much. If I could, I Would vote up your answer but I need 15 reputation points for that :-D